# How to prefetch and use a JSON resource?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to prefetch a JSON resource and use it later in my JavaScript code when necessary.

I'm prefetching with:

```html
<link rel="prefetch" href="/data.json" as="fetch">
```

But I don't know how to access this resource. As the data is loaded and cached, I thought that a `fetch` request would use the cache, but it is making a second request to the server (that I would like to avoid).

```js
// a second request is sent to server instead of using the cache
fetch('/data.json').then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Chrome DevTools with the option **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)** enabled, so `fetch` was always sending a new request to the server without looking in the cache. After disabling this option, the resource is correctly retrieved from cache.

[image: showing in devtools that the second request was loaded from cache]

In the image above (DevTools network tab), the first line shows the request that was done to the server using the `prefetch`:

```html
<link rel="prefetch" href="/data.json" as="fetch">
```

And the second line shows that I've done a `fetch`, but instead of going to the server again, the browser loaded the resource from the cache.

I've accessed the JSON file using the following:

```js
// executed in a click event after the data.json was already prefetched
fetch('/data.json')
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }

        return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json); // do something
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to use "preload" instead of "prefetch", like so:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/data.json" as="fetch"/>
```

see the answer on this thread: [Can link prefetch be used to cache a JSON API response for a later XHR request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593535/can-link-prefetch-be-used-to-cache-a-json-api-response-for-a-later-xhr-request)

and also check out the mdn documents for preload: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Comment: Sorry, but I'm sure that I want to prefetch (download something that might be necessary in the future with low priority) instead of preload (force the browser to download something with high priority).

Comment: mdn mentions that preload is higher priority than prefetch, but that makes sense to me — i don't think the priority is any higher than you'd want — however, alternatively, you can just write a `fetch()` call to execute whenever you want, store that result, and then make use of it later on — this is something you can manage manually, and choose to start loading whenever you want (perhaps after page load)

Comment: Thanks, but prefetching manually is something that I've done in the past in another project. I would prefer now to use the modern `<link rel="prefetch">` to do it automatically.